# Meaning of 来锻炼 in the conversation

Tags: meaning-in-context

**What is the meaning of 来锻炼 in this conversation?**

A: 老师，您每天都来锻炼吗？

B： 对，我每天都坚持锻炼。

I think the question means “Do you exercise daily?” But I do not know why “来” turns up and its meaning. Please make it clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the sentence, 来 means "come". 来锻炼 means "come and do exercise"

So the question actually means: Do you *come (here) and* do exercise everyday?

Comment: So, any phrase "来 + Verb" means "come (here) and do something", right? For example, I talks to my teacher that "Mary 今天不能来上课" that means "Mary cannot (come here to) take class today."

Comment: That is exactly right!

Answer (score 0):

> So, any phrase "来 + Verb" means "come (here) and do something", right?

No, definitely not.

You can **translate** your sentence into English with:

老师，您每天都来锻炼吗？Teacher, do you come here every day to train?

But that is no guarantee that that is what the Chinese means.

It may just be: Teacher, you every day to train?

I see that kind of English a lot from Chinese students, which makes me think, that is what they really have in their heads. Chinese is not bound by English syntax rules.

These 3 sentences come from [here](http://dict.youdao.com/w/%E6%9D%A5%E9%94%BB%E7%82%BC/#keyfrom=dict2.top).

来锻炼 = to enhance

每个特定模型的覆盖率也许会很低，
The coverage of each specific model may be low
这是因为它们没有经过足够的测试**来锻炼**它们。
this is because, they haven't been through enough tests to enhance them

来锻炼 = to enhance

雇主们认为留在学校继续念更高的学位不如去做那些没有报酬的工作**来锻炼**你的能力。
Employers believe, staying in college to continue studying for a higher academic position is not as good as doing some voluntary work to enhance your abilities.

来锻炼 = to enhance

聪明人不需要购买软件或是加入昂贵的研究讲习会，
Clever people don't need to buy software or join expensive study forums,
他们自己能找到新方法**来锻炼**大脑。
they can find new ways to enhance their intelligence for themselves.

Comment: I often run into the same phrase with 来. For example, I think 来电话 does not mean “come and phone me”, but means “phone me”?

Comment: You are right, 来 does not always mean come. One use of 来 is to indicate direction. 过来 will get translated come here, but actually it says pass from. 我过去 gets translated as I'm coming, but it really says I pass to. In German we have 2 little words hin = to and her (say hair) = from They are the same as 来 and 去. They indicate direction to or from. Just depends on your point of view, where you are standing, you either to or from, so to speak.